# Can Neo4j work with Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, neo4j

Can Neo4j work with Hadoop, for social network analysis of big data? If yes, is it hard to make them work together, and what is the bottleneck in such a system?

Basically, I am looking for a solution for social network analysis of big data, and the network could be of hundreds of millions of vertices. I am also expecting a user-friendly GUI for interactive exploring and analysis of graphs. Will Hadoop+Neo4j be good for above purpose? Or is Hadoop+Griph or Spark+GraphX better solution?

Any comments or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: [neo4j-mazerunner](https://github.com/kbastani/neo4j-mazerunner) may be of interest.

Answer (score -3):

Spark + GraphX give you a faster performance. This is derived Pregal and GraphLab libs. But it doesnt has any UI to see graph output directly. User should have their own UI or can extend any graph example from D3 library,

check this link to know further about spark + graphx : 
https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/graphx-programming-guide.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While answers such as this may be relevant, it is recommended that you make an effort to provide some of the relevant information from the link provided in your answer.  Changes to the linked page can change the usefulness of a Link Only Answer.